# Is average total energy of two objects is the sum of their individual average energies?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In the context of Boltzmann's distribution, Schroeder states that an average is defined as
$$\bar{x}=\frac1Z\sum_sx(s)e^{-\beta E(s)}$$

Where $\beta=1/kT$ and E(s) is the energy corresponding to the state ${s}$

Then he states:

> One nice feature of average values is that they are additive; for example, the
> average total energy of two objects is the sum of their individual average energies.

Is this statement correct?

Consider two systems, ${E_1(s_1)}$ and ${E_2(s_2)}$

First off how are we even supposed to calculate the average of this combined system? The summation carries on $s_1$ and $s_2$ which might be different.

Their individual average energies, however, are straightforward

$$\bar{E_1}=\frac1{Z_1}\sum_{s_1}E(s_1)e^{-\beta_1 E(s_1)}\tag1$$
$$\bar{E_2}=\frac1{Z_2}\sum_{s_2}E(s_2)e^{-\beta_2 E(s_2)}\tag2$$

Assuming $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta$ and that there is a meaningful way to correspond every $s_1$ with every $s_2$, which I'll simply call s for the whole system, the average energy of the whole system is then

$$\overline{E_1+E_2}=\frac1{Z_1Z_2}\sum_{s}(E_1(s)+E_2(s))e^{-\beta (E_1(s)+E_2(s))}$$

Since $Z=Z_1Z_2$

This is not the same as the sum of (1) and (2).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose the parameters of each system *separately*.  By writing $E_1(s) + E_2(s)$, you're neglecting the states where the $s$'s aren't the same. That is, there is a state specified by $(s_1,s_2)$ whose energy is $E_1(s_1) + E_2(s_2)$. Once you've realized that, then you have a double sum $\sum_{s_1}\sum_{s_2}$, and from there it's straightforward to show that the result is the sum of the averages.

All of this assumes that the two systems are *independent*, which allows you to specify the states of each one separately and write the combined state as $(s_1,s_2)$.

---

In addition, $\beta_1 = \beta_2$ by assumption: they are assumed to be in thermal equilibrium so that the temperatures are the same.  Otherwise, it's unclear that you can even *define* an average energy for the entire system.